# 403 when trying to download a remote image

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to download pictures from some urls. For some pictures it works fine, but for others I get 403 errors.

For exemple, this one: http://blog.zenika.com/themes/Zenika/img/zenika.gif

This picture access does not require any authentication. You can click yourself on the link and verify that it is available to your browser with a 200 status code.

The following code produces an exception: `new java.net.URL(url).openStream()`. Same for `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new java.net.URL(url), tmp)` whichs uses the same `openStream()` metho under the hood.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://blog.zenika.com/themes/Zenika/img/zenika.gif
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
at services.impl.DefaultStampleServiceComponent$RemoteImgUrlFilter$class.downloadAsTemporaryFile(DefaultStampleServiceComponent.scala:548) [classes/:na]
at services.impl.DefaultStampleServiceComponent$RemoteImgUrlFilter$class.services$impl$DefaultStampleServiceComponent$RemoteImgUrlFilter$$handleImageUrl(DefaultStampleServiceComponent.scala:523) [classes/:na]
```

---

I develop with Scala / Play Framework. I tried to use the built-in AsyncHttpClient.

```
// TODO it could be better to use itetarees on the GET call becase I think AHC load the whole body in memory
WS.url(url).get.flatMap { res =>
  if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
    val bodyStream = res.getAHCResponse.getResponseBodyAsStream
    val futureFile = TryUtils.tryToFuture(createTemporaryFile(bodyStream))
    play.api.Logger.info(s"Successfully downloaded file $filename with status code ${res.status}")
    futureFile
  } else {
    Future.failed(new RuntimeException(s"Download of file $filename returned status code ${res.status}"))
  }
} recover {
  case NonFatal(e) => throw new RuntimeException(s"Could not downloadAsTemporaryFile url=$url", e)
}
```

With this AHC code, it works fine. Can someone explain this behavior and why I got a 403 error with the `URL.openStream()` method?

Comment: How much requests do you fire? Just an assumption - maybe you get kicked for exceeding the request limit?

Comment: @serejja it is just a single request, and I have this problem on different services hosting images. Maybe you can try yourself doing a single `new java.net.URL(url).openStream()` on this url and see by yourself this is not a spam protection

Comment: Some image hosters trying to avoid bots from downloading images, so if they realize that request isn't sent from browser they just response with 403 status, try to check if ie pure curl request from commandline  gives you correct image

Comment: @biesior The URL in the question works without a problem if I just download the image with `curl`.

Comment: @Carsten @biesior the default user agent used by AHC seems to be `NING/1.0`. I don't know which user agent is used by `openStream()`

Comment: @SebastienLorber openStream() seems to be User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_21\r\n for example

Comment: While curl uses curl/7.32.0 as UserAgent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned, some hoster prevent this intrusion using some header like UserAgent :

This doesn't work :

```
   val urls = """http://blog.zenika.com/themes/Zenika/img/zenika.gif"""
  val url = new URL(urls)
  val urlConnection = url.openConnection() 
  val inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()
  val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
```

This works :

```
val urls = """http://blog.zenika.com/themes/Zenika/img/zenika.gif"""
val url = new URL(urls)
val urlConnection = url.openConnection()   
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", """NING/1.0""") 
val inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()
val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the "User-Agent", it still didn't work.