# 403 error for loading image from http and not https

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, http

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958559/403-when-trying-to-download-a-remote-image), but I'm using html & javascript only.

If I try to load this image over https it shows the image just fine.

```
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX100.jpg">
```

Except for this warning

> Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX100.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

But over http it produces this 403 error.

> GET http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjEyMjcyNDI4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDA5Mzg3OA@@._V1_SX100.jpg 403 (Forbidden)

I don't understand why because the image url is http.
Any idea what to do?

Many thanks !

Comment: At least explain the downvotes please.

Answer (score 3):

It's called "[bandwidth theft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking)" or rather prevention thereof.

Over HTTPS your referrer doesn't get sent, but over HTTP it does. In the latter case, IMDb apparently refuses to show their assets on your site. This is also shown if you visit the URL: *"Referral Denied"*.

You are [not allowed to link to or rehost IMDb assets](http://www.imdb.com/conditions):

> Framing: You may not frame or utilize framing techniques to enclose any trademark, logo, or other proprietary information (including images, text, page layout, or form) of IMDb without express written consent.